# How to combine multiple SVG images into single one?

Tags: c#, svg

I have some `SVG` files that i want to combine into single file. I'm trying `svg-net` and library really can combine images but i can't to center images. Trying set `X and Y` for `Children` but `X and Y` are still 0 in result file.

```
var svgResult = new SvgDocument();
var svgBorder = SvgDocument.Open(borderFile);
svgBorder.X = 0;
svgBorder.Y = 0;
svgBorder.Overflow = SvgOverflow.Inherit;
svgBorder.AspectRatio = new Svg.SvgAspectRatio(SvgPreserveAspectRatio.xMidYMid);

svgResult.X = 0;
svgResult.Y = 0;
svgResult.Overflow = SvgOverflow.Inherit;
svgResult.AspectRatio = new Svg.SvgAspectRatio(SvgPreserveAspectRatio.xMidYMid);
svgResult.Children.Add(svgBorder);

for (var i = 0; i < fileNames.Count - 1; i++)
{
    var svgPart = SvgDocument.Open(fileNames[i + 1].name);
    svgPart.X = (svgBorder.Width / 2) - (svgPart.Width / 2);
    svgPart.Y = (svgBorder.Height / 2) - (svgPart.Height / 2);
    svgPart.Overflow = SvgOverflow.Inherit;
    svgPart.AspectRatio = new Svg.SvgAspectRatio(SvgPreserveAspectRatio.xMidYMid);

    svgResult.Children.Add(svgPart);
}
if (!File.Exists(svgResultPath))
    svgResult.Write(svgResultPath);
```

What can i miss? Or maybe i'm using a wrong tool?

Comment: Are you creating some kind of sprite sheet or how will the images be used in the end?

Comment: @chrwahl My goal is combine some images in a single one and after use it as a regular svg marker in Openlayers map.

Comment: So you don't need to position them side by side or something like that. You just need to refer to IDs and use them in a map?